# Can not successfully re-install MYSQL 10.8.2

Tags: command-line, macos, mysql

Removed the old installation as explained here:

https://superuser.com/questions/129193/how-do-i-uninstall-mysql-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard

Installed the package contained in the mysql 5.1.67 DMG downloaded from MySql.com
Installed the preference pane item
Installed the startup item [THIS FAILED]

MySql will not load, it's preference pane show the error message displayed below:

```
 The MySql database server installation was not found. 
 Please make sure the /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin file is present
```

I don't have much familiarity with unix commands so I'm not clear how to troubleshoot this further.

Comment: Is /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin present? If so what does running it in Terminal show?

Comment: UPDATE: I downloaded the 32-bit package (I had previously installed the 64 bit one) and it is installed. However, it will not run still. The error message in the preference pane now says: "Warning - The /Users/snp/emaildb/  directory is not owned by the 'mysql or _mysql user"

Comment: That user directory is nothing to do with a plain mysql install- you must have some configuration or other program using it (and probably mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall the lates version completely and install the new one. According to your error log i think that you have another mysql server running on your machine. Try to find it out and uninstall it.

Comment: Ok so I did a complete uninstall again. Also uninstalled Logitech Media Server which is the only other thing on my system using sql. Rebooted. Did another install of the x64 bit version. Now I am back to getting the message that the MySql Database Server installation was not found, despite the fact that the installer reported a successful install.

Comment: I tried another install, this one fails and reports these errors: (can't display them not enough characters available)

Comment: try to make an update on OS. may be this can help you

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem after installing mySql through homebrew `brew install mysql`.

After digging for a while, I realized that the problem was a missing symbolic link.

Since my `mySql` was installed in `/usr/local/mysql-5.6.12-osx10.7-x86_64` and not in `/usr/local/mysql` as expected, all I did was create the symbolic link to map this missing path:

```
cd /usr/local
sudo ln -s mysql-5.6.12-osx10.7-x86_64 mysql
```

Now I can access `/usr/local/mysql`, and the mySql on System Preferences works fine.